# Fscommand not working in IE9 beta?

Tags: vbscript, internet-explorer-9

On Windows 7 32 bit, Internet Explorer 9 Beta

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
<!--

 Sub Captivate_FSCommand(ByVal command, ByVal args)

  Call Captivate_DoFSCommand(command, args)

 End Sub
//- ->
</SCRIPT>
```

Above the code, but it is calling the JavaScript function in IE9. It is working with IE8, IE7 and Firefox 3.0 or higher.

Answer (score -3):

You can call javascript from AS2 like this:

```
getURL("javascript:functionname();","_parent");
```

This vbscript/fscommand is a garbage. It was old five years ago and stop messing with AS2 because I'm the guy that has to debug your stuff. Let it die already.